# Android Studio error: package com.sun.xxx.xxx. does not exist

Tags: java, android, android-studio

After importing a working project (with libraries) from Eclipse to Android Studio I got the following error.

```
Error:(28, 50) error: package com.sun.xml.internal.bind.CycleRecoverable does not exist
```

After some research I added the following line to my gradle file - to no avail.

```
apply plugin: 'java'

// test line below
compileJava.options.compilerArgs << "-XDignore.symbol.file"
// end 

dependencies {
    compile files('-android/libs/gdx-backend-android.jar')
    compile files('libs/gdx.jar')
    compile files('libs/gdx-sources.jar')

}
```

The question is: How do I get Android Studio to recognize the com.sun... package ?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your Eclipse project was a J2SE / ME project, and that the library you were using isn't included in the Android environment. The solution is to find/use the Android version of what you were using.

Comment: The library is included but it fails to build because "import com.sun.xxx" statement fails...am I going down the wrong path by attempting to get AStudio to recognize it ?